# IText7> How to add a content of PdfCanvas as PdfName.Figure for PDF/UA Accessibility

Tags: java, itext7

I would like to add an element in PdfCanvas, codes as below. Why I can't see the "Figure" in document tag?

```
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.addNewPage());
canvas.beginText();
canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 12);
canvas.showText("Test for Accessibility");
canvas.stroke();

PdfDictionary dict = new PdfDictionary();
dict.put(PdfName.Span, new PdfString("Eyes Wide Shut"));      
canvas.beginMarkedContent(PdfName.Figure, dict);
canvas.newlineShowText("EWS");
canvas.endMarkedContent();
canvas.endText();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your code is not complete so we don't even know if you call `setTagged()` on a `PdfDocument` instance (which is a must for tagging).

But the bigger problem is that `beginMarkedContent` on its own does not add any connections from the content to the tag tree. The best way to add those connections is use `TagTreePointer` (if you really want to use low-level `PdfCanvas` API). You can manipulate tree structure with `TagTreePointer` and add connections between tree and content with `PdfCanvas#openTag`.

Also, you seem to be trying to add expansion text (`Eyes Wide Shut`) with `dict.put(PdfName.Span, new PdfString("Eyes Wide Shut"));`, but from the PDF syntax point of view this expression does not do anything useful. `TagTreePointer`'s API allows you to set expansion text easily as well.

All in all, the complete code would look like following:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFilePath));
pdfDocument.setTagged();

PdfPage firstPage = pdfDocument.addNewPage();

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(firstPage);

TagTreePointer tagPointer = new TagTreePointer(pdfDocument);
tagPointer.setPageForTagging(firstPage);
tagPointer.addTag(StandardRoles.P).addTag(StandardRoles.SPAN);

canvas.beginText()
        .setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(), 12)
        .openTag(tagPointer.getTagReference())
        .showText("Test for Accessibility")
        .closeTag()
        .stroke();

tagPointer.moveToParent().addTag(StandardRoles.SPAN).getProperties().setExpansion("Eyes Wide Shut");
canvas.openTag(tagPointer.getTagReference())
        .newlineShowText("EWS")
        .closeTag()
        .endText();

pdfDocument.close();
```

The resultant tag structure:

[image: tag structure]