# How do you add a paragraph to an existing WCAG compliant PDF using iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7, wcag

I'm trying to use [itext7](/questions/tagged/itext7) to a paragraph to the top of an existing [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) that is and must remain [wcag](/questions/tagged/wcag) compliant. The new paragraph must also be the first element in the logical structure to preserve the natural reading order.

The following iText7 8.0 [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code almost does the job:

```
using var pdfReader = new PdfReader("wcag-compliant.pdf");
pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
var outputPath = "new-wcag-compliant.pdf";
using var writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)).SetSmartMode(true);
using var pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(pdfReader, writer);
using var document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdfDocument);
var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Arial.ttf"), PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);
var pageSize = pdfDocument.GetPage(1).GetPageSize();
var p = new Paragraph().SetFixedPosition(65, pageSize.GetHeight() - 80, 200);
var text = new Text("Text of new paragraph");
p.Add(text).SetFont(font);
p.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetAlternateDescription("Description of new paragraph");
pdfDocument.GetTagStructureContext().GetAutoTaggingPointer().AddTag(0, p.GetAccessibilityProperties());
document.Add(p);
document.Close();
```

Unfortunately, the new paragraph gets wrapped in another paragraph in the tagging structure which is a violation of WCAG as shown here with the [PAC tool](https://pdfua.foundation/en/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac/register/):

[image]

What is the correct way to add new text to an existing WCAG compliant PDF and at the same time placing that text in the logical structure in a suitable place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a solution using the [higher-level API](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/latest/namespacei_text_1_1_layout.html) with Paragraph ect., but with inspiration from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53995362/2969216) I found a more low-level solution using PdfCanvas:

```
using var pdfReader = new PdfReader("wcag-compliant.pdf");
pdfReader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
var outputPath = "new-wcag-compliant.pdf";
using var writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)).SetSmartMode(true);
using var pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(pdfReader, writer);
using var document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdfDocument);
var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Arial.ttf"), PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);
var firstPage = pdfDocument.GetPage(1);
var canvas = new PdfCanvas(firstPage);
var ttp = new TagTreePointer(pdfDocument);
ttp.SetPageForTagging(firstPage);
ttp.AddTag(0, StandardRoles.P);
canvas.BeginText()
        .SetFontAndSize(font, 8)
        .OpenTag(ttp.GetTagReference())
        .MoveText(65, firstPage.GetPageSize().GetTop() - 80)
        .ShowText(text)
        .CloseTag()
        .EndText();
document.Close();
```

This code adds the new text in a new paragraph which is placed as the first element of the logical structure.